# ошибка input_shape = X_train.shape[1] # Размер входных данных ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'shape'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

[image]

```
ошибка input_shape = X_train.shape[1] # Размер входных данных 
^^^^^^^^^^^^^ AttributeError: 'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

Я пробовал другие названия, не помогло. Я думаю, что это ошибка в версии.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Комментарии в коде по ссылке на приличном русском, "вопрос" на ломаном суржике по сути сводится к тому, что вам непонятно сообщение на английском об ошибке `'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'shape'`.  А это сообщение намекает, что у вас тупо не определены входные данные о фигурах в переменной `X_train`, на что, собственно, и намекал настоящий автор кода, оставив многоточие.

Comment: Вставьте код текстом в сам вопрос

Comment: Ошибка в том, что вместо многоточия нужно вписать свои данные, а вы этого не сделали.

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что когда вы пишите
X_input = ...
Ему присваивается значение класс Ellipsis, который не содержит аттрибута shape.Чтобы решить проблему, вам надо подробно объяснить что вы хотели сделать.

Comment: Да там просто надо было вписать свои данные вместо многоточия, но автор вопроса этого не сделал и запустил код прямо как есть.